# react-select avoid formatting for selected option

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I am using react-select control in my form.
Using formatOptionLabel method, i have customized to display options in different format.

```js
<Select
  className="basic-single"
  classNamePrefix="Select"
  isClearable={true}
  isSearchable={true}
  isMulti
  value={this.state.myselectedvalue}
  options={this.state.myoptions}
  onChange={(value) => this.setState({ myselectedvalue: value })}
  isDisabled={this.state.Disabled}
  formatOptionLabel={formatResult}
/>
```

```js
const formatResult = (item: any) => {
  let imageurl = 'https://mywebsite/' + item.countrycode + '.gif';
  return (
    <div>
      <div className={styles.Optiontablerow}>
        <div className={styles.OptionImageCell}>
          <img src={imageurl}></img>
        </div>
        <div className={styles.Optiontablecell}>{item.label}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Now when i select the option, same format is appearing in selected options.
For selected options how to avoid this formatting?
Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done conditional formatting and resolved this issue.

```
const formatResult = (item: any) => {
let imageurl = 'https://mywebsite/' + item.countrycode + '.gif';
  return (    <div>
{item.isSelectedOption==false?
      <div className={styles.Optiontablerow}>
        <div className={styles.OptionImageCell}>
          <img src={imageurl}></img>
        </div>
        <div className={styles.Optiontablecell}>{item.label}</div>
      </div>:{item.label}}
    </div>
  )
}
```